# Structure reference (.) operator works on class name in vc9

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code compiles on my version of vc9:

```
wstring test2;
if (test2.find(L'c') == wstring.npos)
{
}
```

but by itself

```
wstring.npos;
```

does not.  (`wstring::npos;` works fine) To my mind, this is 100% wrong. At first I thought maybe a wstring was being constructed and the npos member was being accessed ala `wstring().npos`, but a quick attempt to step into the line suggested otherwise. simulating this same situation with a class of my own results in

> warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'Foo'

but still compiles.

Just for my sanity - this syntax should not work, right? And given that it does work, why would the expression `wstring.npos;` fail?

Comment: Are you sure it was `wstring.npos` that compiled and not `test2.npos`?

Comment: I'm sure, just very surprised!

Comment: Then it's non-standard behaviour, which, to be honest, is to be expected of MSVC.

Comment: I wonder if this could be reproduced using a template and typedef. (Remember, `std::wstring` is really `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`.)

Comment: @aschepler, If it calms your mind, it [doesn't compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/HKRrf$0) on GCC.

Comment: @chris: I wasn't worried.  This is obviously either a compiler bug or a misunderstanding, not a quirk of real C++.

Comment: Did you try to disable language extensions?

Comment: @andreyT Good suggestion, unfortunately that doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4):

`wstring.npos` should **not** work, because `npos` is a `static` member and it can be accessed with the class name with the scope resolution operator (`wstring::npos`) or via a class *instance* with the dot operator (`wstring str; str.npos;`).

Comment: Any thoughts on why the expression `wstring.npos;` doesn't compile, in context?  My guess coming here was that this was a case of VC9 being a little too lenient with its parsing rules when it knows a particular token is going to be an rvalue, whereas the `wstring.npos;` is being processed as a variable declaration of type wstring with improper syntax.  My goal in posting was more to understand "technically, why is this happening" than simply "is this standards compliant", though I don't know that I am likely to get more of an answer than has already been provided.

Comment: @Rollie "Any thoughts on why the expression wstring.npos; doesn't compile, in context?"... it doesn't compile because it's invalid. I just said that.

Comment: "In context" meaning: what is different about that expression that makes it fail to compile, vs `if (find(...) == wstring.npos)`

Comment: @Rollie I don't know, you might get lucky and have someone from MS answer that, or take it to the MS forums (possibly file a bug report, because it's definitely not legal)

Answer (score 1):

> Then it's non-standard behaviour, which, to be honest, is to be expected of MSVC

I am sometimes baffled why the assumption is made that MS is guilty without checking validity of the claim.

**wstring.npos does not compile** and VS 2008 as well as 2010 flags an error.

Why it does not compile, is explained correctly in previous posts.

Comment: Kudos for not jumping on the anti-MS bandwagon, and actually taking the time to verify an issue. But it really *does* compile on my version of VC9: http://i.imgur.com/8e9vk.jpg

if it isn't compiling on yours, I would be interested to know what the difference might be between our versions!

Answer (score 0):

because npos is a static member of the class.